# Java ArrayList Not removing

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a global arrayList of an arrayList of Strings and when I print out the size it prints 10. I'm then trying to remove the first arrayList so that I just have a list of strings. But when I print out the size of the "removed list" it returns 0. Any help?

```
System.out.println(stateArrays.size());
ArrayList<String> list = stateArrays.remove(0);
System.out.println(list.size());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `stateArrays.size()` in the second print?

Comment: That code does not look compilable. Is 'stateArrays' a list of lists?

Comment: That code doesn't compile unless stateArrays is `List<ArrayList<String>>` in which case the problem should be .. evident. Note that `remove(int)` [returns the *removed* item](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)).

Comment: first make stateArray.remove(); and then pass it to list

Answer (score 2):

What the remove() method returns is the element removed. So if you want to print the new length of stateArrays, just repeat the first line.